# Bind a property in xaml template to viewmodel (RibbonTextBox)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Background info of larger problem**
The problem I am trying to solve is to allow a user to set the MinWidth of the label inside of the RibbonTextBox control template. I intend to the same with other properties once I can figure out the first one. The aim of this is to be able to align RibbonTextBoxes stacked on top of each other by setting widths. I am so far solved my problem by hardcoding the values in the control template. I would like to make this control reusable and thus need to be able to set up some binding.

**The problem that needs solving**
I have the following xaml (lots of xaml has been removed for readability). At the centre of this xaml you can see a label. That label has a `MinWidth` property which is the focus of my question.

```
<DataTemplate x:Uid="DataTemplate_0" DataType="{x:Type element:RibbonTextBoxVM}">
    <ribbon:RibbonTextBox x:Uid="ribbon:RibbonTextBox_1" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding Text}" Label="{Binding Label}" >
        <ribbon:RibbonTextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonTextBox}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Margin='2,0,0,0' Padding='0,0,0,5' BorderThickness='0,0,0,0' HorizontalAlignment='Stretch' VerticalAlignment='Bottom' 
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment='Left' VerticalContentAlignment='Top' Background='#00FFFFFF' FlowDirection='LeftToRight' 
                                       Visibility='Visible' MinWidth="80">
                                    <!--other stuff-->
                                </Label>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ribbon:RibbonTextBox.Style>
    </ribbon:RibbonTextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

The following is the viewmodel that backs the above xaml.

```
public class RibbonTextBoxVM : ViewModel
{
    public string Label
    {
        get { return GetValue(Properties.Label); }
        set { SetValue(Properties.Label, value); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return GetValue(Properties.Text); }
        set { SetValue(Properties.Text, value); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return GetValue(Properties.IsReadOnly); }
        set { SetValue(Properties.IsReadOnly, value); }
    }

    public RibbonTextBoxVM(string text, string label, bool isReadOnly)
    {
        Text = text;
        Label = label;
        IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is have a property LabelMinWidth.

```
public double LabelMinWidth
{
    get { return GetValue(Properties.LabelMinWidth); }
    set { SetValue(Properties.LabelMinWidth, value); }
}
```

I want to allow the user to pass in a value to the constructor to set that property. That is the easy part.

The part I cannot figure out is how to bind my new LabelMinWidth to the MinWidth property of the label inside the control template in the xaml.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great. Ill be happy to answer any questions about the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your In your `RibbonTextBox` has your VM as its `DataContext`, you can use a `Binding`in your `ControlTemplate`, just like you bound the other properties:

```
<Label ... MinWidth="{Binding LabelMinWidth}">
```

This works because in WPF, the `DataContext` inherits to all children (unless overridden). So if you have a property on your VM that you want to bind to in a control in a template, you just bind to it.

Comment: Ill give that a shot. Could you explain how that works? It would help me solve this problem in future if I could understand the mechanics of this solution